# How do i convert my CP into PG?

Tags: bravely-second

After playing for over 5 hours I brought every upgrade in the Chompers Toy Making minigame, including the CP to PG conversion to the point that I should have a `100 CP => 1PG` conversion rate.

However, when I quit I have about 1.6 million CP which should turn out to be 16k in PG. However I don't see this get added to my current fond, and when I re-enter into the minigame I still have 1.6 million CP.

So how can I convert my CP into PG?

NOTE: My Current sport in the game is:

> After Al-kampus where the main plot has me headed to the crescent island to locate the Ba'al there while in the side-story I am going back into Jackel's hideout to look for the cave entrance behind his chair.

Comment: I wondered this too. Apparently there is some in-game location where you can go to exchange cp for pg. But I haven't gotten up to that point yet

Answer (score 2):

Chompshire is where you go to exchange CP into PG, it's south of the Sage's house at a little yellow patch. You will need the air ship to get to it.